# spring cannot find my bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring, in my application I need to connect to Mysql, all my database's configuration are in a bean, when I try to get it,the server gives me this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

this is my servlet-context where I define my bean:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.metmi.mmasgis" />







    <beans:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        autowire-candidate="true">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="username" value="root"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="password" value="password"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springschema">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

this is my controller:

```
    package com.metmi.mmasgis;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader;

import com.metmi.mmasgis.dao.DbImpl;
import com.metmi.mmasgis.model.Db;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Inject
    DbImpl dbs;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "home";
    }

    /**
     * get the database list in Mysql
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/db", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dbs(Locale locale, Model model) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = ContextLoader
                .getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource");
        dbs = new DbImpl();
        dbs.setDataSource(ds);
        ArrayList<Db> dbList = dbs.getDatabases();
        model.addAttribute("dbList", dbList);
        return "dbs";
    }

    /**
     * Simply shows ciao.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ciao", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ciao(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "ciao";
    }

}
```

Comment: We need to see how you're launching your program. I suspect the XML file may not be being read. Also, you should never look up a bean by hand if you can autowire it.

Comment: I can see one more issue in you xml file `<mvc:annotation-driven />` is missing. Post the full stack trace..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your bean declaration to your main application context, not the one where you have DispatcherServlet.